# Populate a new dataframe column with True if two cell values match another smaller subset dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to populate a new dataframe column with True if two cell values match another smaller subset dataframe in pandas, otherwise with a value of False.

For instance, this is original output dataframe I am constructing.

```
ID    Type
1     A
2     B
3     A
4     A
5     C
6     A
7     D
8     A
9     B
10    A
```

And the smaller subset of the dataframe selected based on some criteria:

```
ID    Type
1     A
3     A
4     A
5     C
7     D
10    A
```

What I am trying to accomplish is when ID and Type in the output dataframe match with the smaller subset datadrame, I want to populate a new column called 'Result' and value equals to True. Otherwise, value equals to False.

```
ID    Type    Result
1     A       True
2     B       False
3     A       True
4     A       True
5     C       True
6     A       False
7     D       True
8     A       False
9     B       False
10    A       True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the 2 dataframes using a left merge with the original dataframe as base and turn on the `indicator=` parameter to show the merge result.  Then change the merge result to `True` for the rows that appear in **both** dataframes and `False` otherwise.

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID', 'Type'] , how='left', indicator='Result')
df_out['Result'] = (df_out['Result'] == 'both')
```

**Explanation**:

With `indicator=` parameter turn on, Pandas will show you the merge result of which dataframe the current row are from (in terms of `both`, `left_only` and `right_only`)

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID', 'Type'] , how='left', indicator='Result')

print(df_out)


   ID Type     Result
0   1    A       both
1   2    B  left_only
2   3    A       both
3   4    A       both
4   5    C       both
5   6    A  left_only
6   7    D       both
7   8    A  left_only
8   9    B  left_only
9  10    A       both
```

Then, we transform the `both` and others to `True`/`False` by boolean mask, as follows:

```
df_out['Result'] = (df_out['Result'] == 'both')

print(df_out)



   ID Type  Result
0   1    A    True
1   2    B   False
2   3    A    True
3   4    A    True
4   5    C    True
5   6    A   False
6   7    D    True
7   8    A   False
8   9    B   False
9  10    A    True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. Just one quick follow up: is there anyway we could mark the 'Result' column to Correct when True; otherwise to Incorrect?

Comment: @SkipperLin  You can further use: `df_out['Result'] = np.where(df_out['Result'], 'Correct', 'Incorrect')`  Remember to add the import of `import numpy as np` if you have not yet included it.

Comment: I have 1457 records in my original dataset. As I was keep adding a new column after each validation test I am running, I eventually have 1657 records. Would like to reach out to see if the additional 200 records are because the "ID" and "Type" are not unique. Is there anyway we could make sure no matter how we merge it, it is still 1457 records. Thank you so much.